# How can I prioritize "Add import" over "Ruff: Disable" in Python / VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-python

I'm writing Python code in VS Code and have recently installed the Ruff linter and its associated [VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=charliermarsh.ruff). One thing I'm finding frustrating is that when I write a symbol name and want to use VS Code's "Quick Fix" to add an import for it, the first option that comes up is "Ruff: Disable" rather than "Add import".

[image: Quick Fix showing "Ruff: Disable" first and Add import second]

This isn't the end of the world, of course, I can press down arrow to select the action I want. But it does add an extra step and is an annoyance. Is there a way I can get these actions in the order I want?

A few versions if they're relevant:

- Ruff extension, this happens with both v2023.16.0
  and v2023.17.11351528
- Pylance v2023.6.10
- Python VS Code Extension v2023.8.0

VS Code version:

```
Version: 1.78.2 (Universal)
Commit: b3e4e68a0bc097f0ae7907b217c1119af9e03435
Date: 2023-05-10T14:44:45.204Z
Electron: 22.5.2
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 22.5.0
Sandboxed: Yes
```

Comment: A feature request has existed in[ Github](https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff-vscode/issues/199), and I created [a new one](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/21416) for you in vscode-Python.